# css style to achieve this background effect

Tags: jquery, css

I received a design to convert to a website. It looks great and isn't to challenging, except for the menu.

The menu is a simple accordion menu, but the design itself is getting me under.

Here is what the menu should look like (not dropped and dropped respectively):

[Not Dropped http://photostand.co.za/images/7otfr8llxeeochyq4h4i.jpg](http://photostand.co.za/images/7otfr8llxeeochyq4h4i.jpg)
[Dropped http://photostand.co.za/images/vyzfbxqj4cdiyaxmfbv6.jpg](http://photostand.co.za/images/vyzfbxqj4cdiyaxmfbv6.jpg)

The thing I'm struggling with is the green back bit.

I know how to rotate, but rotate rotates everything.

This is the accordion script I'm using:

```
$("#accordion > li > div").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#accordion { list-style: none; padding: 0 0 0 0; width: 175px; font-size:13px; }
#accordion div { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; cursor: pointer; text-align:center; border:2px black solid; vertical-align:center; height:30px; padding: 5 5 5 7px; list-style: circle; }
#accordion ul { text-align:center; list-style: none; padding: 0 0 0 0; }
#accordion ul { display: none; }
#accordion ul li { font-weight: normal; vertical-align:center; height:30px; cursor: auto; padding: 0 0 0 7px; border: thin solid black; margin-top: 2px; width:110px; margin-left:55px; background:#ffffff; }
#accordion ul li:hover { background:#d0d4d7 }
#accordion a { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
#accordion a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <div>Park Home</div>
    <li><div>Travel</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Activities and Facilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Code of Conduct</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How to get there</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What to Expect</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fees</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div>Fauna and Flora</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Birding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mammals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reptiles and Amphibians</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vegetation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Invertabrates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <div>Construction Progress</div>
    <div>History</div>
    <div>Careers</div>
    <li><div>Contact Us</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enquiries</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could anyone perhaps assist me. Everything I've tried thus far failed.

**UPDATE 1 (20-Sept-12 16:49 CAT)**

I made some progress with this. I actually got it to look how I want it to look. I now just need to have the green bits slide down like the rest. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/pNxBU/1/ (sidenote: The spacing is a bit off since it's taken out of 'context' so to speak.

So now if someone could help me get those things to move with their divs... hmmm...

Comment: Instead of rotating, you should probably use a simple image (of a yet rotated green rectangle with a black border rectangle) as background of your cell.

Comment: @dystroy - spot on. You don't need to do everything in pure CSS. Sometimes images are your friend.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question so I don't know why it's been upvoted. Guys, please focus on the look of the menu. It's a rotated block. The backgrounds follow on each other.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the answer : I suggest to put the **yet rotated** block in the background picture.

Comment: @DarkRanger, is it a fixed menu ? (or dynamic ? in the sense that more items and/or subitems can be added)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, it's a fixed menu.

Comment: @dystroy, and how will it move down as per the dropped down menu in the second picture?

Comment: What is the problem with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code can help you

```
var tranform_property = [ '-moz-transform', '-ms-transform', '-webkit-transform', '-o-transform'];

$("div.rotate-background").each(function(index, element){
   var angle = -((5-(index/2)) * Math.PI) / 180 ;
   var el = $(element);

   for(var i in tranform_property){
     el.css(tranform_property[i], "matrix(" + Math.cos(angle) + "," +
                  Math.sin(angle) + "," +
                  -Math.sin(angle) + "," +
                  Math.cos(angle) + ", " +
                  (-20 + index*2 ) + ", 1)");

     angle = angle * -1;
     el.find(":first-child").css(tranform_property[i], "matrix(" + Math.cos(angle) + "," +
                  Math.sin(angle) + "," +
                  -Math.sin(angle) + "," +
                  Math.cos(angle) + ", " +
                  (15 - index *4) + ", 1)");
  }
});
```

I tested it only on firefox and google-chrome. I provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/LvjJE/3/).

**EDIT :**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/LvjJE/4/) the example it may be look like to the given image.

I give you the [documentation](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/) which help me, if you want adjust the rectangle position

Comment: This looks and works brilliant. I love it. One little issue though is that it's not inline as per my images above. Working for a graphics designer she can be a bit anal about this. So what would I need to change to have those blocks line up properly?

Comment: You just need adjust the number 6 in var angle. It is for the rotation rectangle. And the second is the -20 and the 10 in each matrix. They translate to the right the element. I invited you to test and read the documentation in the post ^^. If I found the good parameter I will change it.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll just keep adjusting it until it looks exactly the way she wants it, but it's fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rotating, you should probably use a simple image (of a yet rotated green rectangle with a black border rectangle over it) as background of your cell.

That is : everything minus the text.

Comment: but it won't look the same then. It will have all the images in a row under each other. Look closely at the background, it's a green block that's been rotated.

Comment: not really, if you notice the design closer the rotated background is not the same in each item of the menu. it is slightly to the right as you go down... and once the menu is open you need to find how right it goes depending on the sub elements..

Comment: You don't have to have the same image for all cells. Simply cut the big one.